# What can I do to make this SQL return results in certain situations?

Tags: mysql, sql

I could use some help to make this search return results in certain situations. The user has 2 fields to fill in and I would like to be able to leave either blank or fill in both. The fields are vehicle and keywords. The vehicle field is meant to allow searching based on the make, model, VIN, truck number (often is 2 - 3 digits or a letter prefix followed by 2 digits), and a few other fields that belong to the truck table. The keywords are meant to search most fields in the maintenance and maintenance_parts tables (things like the description of the work, parts name, parts number). Currently leaving the keywords field blank returns no results even when the vehicle field has valid results of its own.

```
"SELECT M.maintenance_id, M.some_id, M.type_code, M.service_date, M.mileage, M.mg_id, M.mg_type, M.comments, M.work_done,
                MATCH( M.comments, M.work_done) AGAINST( '$keywords' ) +
                MATCH( P.part_num, P.part_desc, P.part_ref) AGAINST( '$keywords' ) +
                MATCH( T.truck_number, T.make, T.model, T.engine, T.vin_number, T.transmission_number, T.comments) AGAINST( '$vehicle' )
                AS score
            FROM maintenance M, maintenance_parts P, truck T
            WHERE M.maintenance_id = P.maintenance_id
            AND M.some_id = T.truck_id
            AND M.type_code = 'truck'
            AND (MATCH( T.truck_number, T.make, T.model, T.engine, T.vin_number, T.transmission_number, T.comments) AGAINST( '$vehicle' )
            OR T.truck_number LIKE '%$vehicle%')
            AND MATCH( P.part_num, P.part_desc, P.part_ref) AGAINST( '$keywords' )
            AND MATCH( M.comments, M.work_done) AGAINST( '$keywords' )
            AND M.status = 'A' GROUP BY maintenance_id ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 0, $limit";
```

Comment: "I could use some help to make this search more efficient and to find better/more results" - by what criteria?

Comment: My main concern is that when the keywords field is blank it find NO results even when there are valid results for what is entered in the vehicle field.

Comment: @Josh: then I suggest you edit your question to reflect that

Comment: This sounds like it breaks first normal form to me.  I don't think it's a good practice to compose several values into a single column.  Correct me if I read it too quickly.

Comment: @duffymo - are you talking about the "MATCH( M.comments, M.work_done) AGAINST( '$keywords' ) + MATCH( P.part_num, P.part_desc, P.part_ref) AGAINST( '$keywords' ) + MATCH( T.truck_number, T.make, T.model, T.engine, T.vin_number, T.transmission_number, T.comments) AGAINST( '$vehicle' ) AS score"?

Comment: That is just adding the scores returned from the Match so that the results can be ordered... Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change some of your ANDs to ORs and then parenthesize the ORs.

Right now you require one of the $vehicle MATCHes and also *both* of the $keyword matches.  Instead, I think you want to require any one of the $vehicle *or* $keyword matches.

Also, I think that you can combine the $keyword matches into a single MATCH call, can't you?  And I think the LIKE check against T.truck_number is redundant given the MATCH that includes that column.  In which case you could write that section of the SQL as:

```
 AND (MATCH( T.truck_number, T.make, T.model, T.engine, T.vin_number,
      T.transmission_number, T.comments) AGAINST( '$vehicle' )
     OR MATCH( P.part_num, P.part_desc, P.part_ref,M.comments, M.work_done) 
     AGAINST( '$keywords' ))
```

And I include the obligatory comment about protecting yourself against SQL injection by escaping the dynamic SQL you create.