# How can I improve this SQL to avoid several problems with its results?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having some problems with trying to search. Currently this will only return results that have at least 1 row in the maintenance_parts table. I would like it to return results even if there are 0 parts rows.

My second problem is that when you search for a vehicle and it should return multiple results (multiple maintenance rows) it will only return 1 result for that vehicle.

**Some Background Info:**
The user has 2 fields to fill out. The fields are vehicle and keywords. The vehicle field is meant to allow searching based on the make, model, VIN, truck number (often is 2 - 3 digits or a letter prefix followed by 2 digits), and a few other fields that belong to the truck table. The keywords are meant to search most fields in the maintenance and maintenance_parts tables (things like the description of the work, parts name, parts number).

The maintenance_parts table can contain 0, 1, or more rows for each maintenance row. The truck table contains exactly 1 row for every maintenance row. A truck can have multiple maintenance records.

```
 "SELECT M.maintenance_id, M.some_id, M.type_code, M.service_date, M.mileage, M.mg_id, M.mg_type, M.comments, M.work_done,
                    MATCH( M.comments, M.work_done) AGAINST( '$keywords' ) +
                    MATCH( P.part_num, P.part_desc, P.part_ref) AGAINST( '$keywords' ) +
                    MATCH( T.truck_number, T.make, T.model, T.engine, T.vin_number, T.transmission_number, T.comments) AGAINST( '$vehicle' )
                    AS score
                FROM maintenance M, maintenance_parts P, truck T
                WHERE M.maintenance_id = P.maintenance_id
                AND M.some_id = T.truck_id
                AND M.type_code = 'truck'
                AND (
                    (MATCH( T.truck_number, T.make, T.model, T.engine, T.vin_number, T.transmission_number, T.comments) AGAINST( '$vehicle' )
                    OR T.truck_number LIKE '%$vehicle%')
                    OR MATCH( P.part_num, P.part_desc, P.part_ref) AGAINST( '$keywords' )
                    OR MATCH( M.comments, M.work_done) AGAINST( '$keywords' )
                )
                AND M.status = 'A' GROUP BY maintenance_id ORDER BY score DESC, maintenance_id DESC LIMIT 0, $limit"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can I do to make this SQL return results in certain situations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576473/what-can-i-do-to-make-this-sql-return-results-in-certain-situations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does a JOIN between Maintenance and Maintenace_parts   The first thing you will need to do is convert this to a LEFT JOIN

```
  FROM maintenance M 
  JOIN truck T ON t.truck_id=M.some_id 
  LEFT JOIN maintenance_parts P ON M.maintenance_id = P.maintenance_id
  WHERE...
```

After you do this, you will get null values for every column in maintenance_parts if a matching row is not found.   It appears your code will be OK with this, but make sure your select and where clause MATCH function properly work with NULLs

Code to check/review that is works properly with NULLS is the following

```
 OR MATCH( P.part_num, P.part_desc, P.part_ref) AGAINST( '$keywords' )
```

The second problems appears to be that you are grouping by **maintenance_id** instead of **truck_id**.   Try changing the GROUP BY field, it should solve your second issue

**Revised query below**

```
    SELECT T.TRUCK_ID,M.maintenance_id, M.some_id, M.type_code, M.service_date, 
           M.mileage, M.mg_id, M.mg_type, M.comments, M.work_done,
           MATCH( M.comments, M.work_done) AGAINST( '$keywords' ) +
           IfNull(P.PartScore,0) +
           MATCH( T.truck_number, T.make, T.model, T.engine, T.vin_number, T.transmission_number, T.comments) AGAINST( '$vehicle' )
           AS score
                    FROM maintenance M, 
                    JOIN 

                    (SELECT Truck_id,truck_number, make, model, engine, vin_number,            transmission_number,comments FROM Truck
UNION
SELECT Truck_id,truck_number, make, model, engine, vin_number,            transmission_number,comments FROM Trailer
)  

T 
                     ON M.some_id=T.Truck_id
                    LEFT JOIN 
                    (SELECT maintenance_id,SUM(MATCH( P.part_num, P.part_desc, P.part_ref)               AGAINST( '$keywords' )) AS PartScore
                     FROM  maintenance_parts
                     GROUP BY maintenance_id ) P
                    P ON M.maintenance_id = P.maintenance_id
                    WHERE M.type_code = 'truck'
                    AND (
                        (MATCH( T.truck_number, T.make, T.model, T.engine, T.vin_number, T.transmission_number, T.comments) AGAINST( '$vehicle' )
                        OR T.truck_number LIKE '%$vehicle%')
                        OR MATCH( P.part_num, P.part_desc, P.part_ref) AGAINST( '$keywords' )
                        OR MATCH( M.comments, M.work_done) AGAINST( '$keywords' )
                    )
                    AND M.status = 'A' 
    ORDER BY score DESC, maintenance_id DESC 
    LIMIT 0, $limit"
```

Comment: I get: #1054 - Unknown column 'M.maintenance_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: That is a surprise, since the original code found it out.   I've edited the answer to convert to using the JOIN method for all tables, there might be something in MYSQL that doesn't let you mix methods.  Try that...

Comment: Also, the field maintenance_id in the select clause must be replaced with TRUCK_ID when you change the group by.   Why are you using the GROUP BY anyway, it appears you don't need it...

Comment: I think at one point I needed the GROUP BY but changed a bunch of things and just forgot to get rid of it.

Comment: Correction, I do need it. It was so that I do not have a row for each maintenance_part returned. I need to search the parts rows but I just need the Truck and Maintenance Info returned.

Comment: Try my revised query, it should work and you shouldn't need the group by

Comment: Nope, that still selects a row for each of the parts since some have multiple parts per maintenance row.

Comment: What do you want to do in your SELECT clause if there are multiple parts (i.e. which of the multiple rows do you want to be considered when computing the score)?

Comment: For the score I want to consider all of the parts rows for the maintenance row. I only need to select the maintenance and truck info. I do not need to select the parts info, just use it to calculate the score.

Comment: OK, so you need to correlation value returned by the MATCH function?  I'll modify the answer since there is not a lot of area to write in the comment window

Comment: Another question. The some_id is the key to either the Truck or Trailer tables. The type_code contains either 'truck' or 'trailer' to specify which table the some_id refers to. (I am not the one who designed this). Is there anyway to do the Join with both the truck and trailer tables at the same time?

Comment: I don't use mySQL that much, so I am not that familiar with what MATCH returns, so you might need to use a MAX() instead of a SUM() in the inner query (the part that computes PartScore).   Hope I got you close enough to tweak the rest

Comment: Do the Truck and Trailer tables contain the same fields?

Comment: there are a few differences, but mostly the same. Truck has a few extra fields.

Comment: Then you can do this- UNION the two tables into one part, I'll modify the answer again....

Comment: If you can use the UNION statement above, you should remove the type_code='TRUCK' from the WHERE clause as well...